# Receiving "TypeError: i is not a function" when looking at some questions on SO

Tags: bug, status-completed

It seems that for some question pages, I receive the error `TypeError: i is not a function` in the console.

For example for the question [what can you do when window.location.href returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007837/what-can-you-do-when-window-location-href-returns-null), the error is pointing to line 1398, column 463 of the page. That line is a `<script>` block that contains this minified code, that I beautified here:

```js
window.clc_request = 'AoZ7GBgpv9QIUv1ZAF02UwICAAAAAgAAAANAAAAAfGphdmFzY3JpcHR8eC11c2VyLXJlZ2lzdGVyZWR8eC01MDAwcGx1cy1yZXB8eC1wZXJzb25hLWZyb250ZW5kfACRZGCvJBE00Zr8';;
! function i(n) {
  var u, r;
  try {
    if ("function" != typeof [].indexOf) return;
    if (!window.addEventListener) return;
    if (!n.allowed) return;
    if (!RegExp(n.allowed).test(location.hostname)) return;
    var t = window,
      i = t.document,
      f = n.wv;
    if (i.hidden && f) return void i.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function t() {
      i.hidden || (i(n), i.removeEventListener("visibilitychange", t))
    });
    if (t.clc = t.clc || {}, t.clc.init = t.clc.init || [], n.autoload && t.clc.init.push(function(n) {
        return n.load()
      }), t.clc.options) {
      for (u in t.clc.options) n[u] = t.clc.options[u];
      t.clc.options = n
    } else t.clc.options = n;
    r = i.createElement("script");
    r.async = !0;
    r.src = n.lib;
    i.body.appendChild(r)
  } catch (i) {}
}.call(null, {
  "lib": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/clc/clc.min.js?v=d80e98d967bf",
  "u": "https://clc.stackoverflow.com/markup.js",
  "azw": true,
  "kt": 2000,
  "tto": true,
  "d": {
    "sb": ["hireme", "clc-sb"],
    "tlb": ["careers1", "clc-tlb"],
    "mlb": ["careers3", "clc-mlb"]
  },
  "h": "clc.stackoverflow.com",
  "autoload": true,
  "allowed": "^(((talent\\.)?stackoverflow)|(blog\\.codinghorror)|(serverfault|askubuntu)|([^\\.]+\\.stackexchange))\\.com$",
  "wv": true
});
```

The stack trace includes the function `t`, which is the `visibilitychange` event listener. Indeed, whenever I switch to a different tab, then switch back, the error counter increases by one.

The outer function is already called `i`, but `i` is also used as a local variable inside it that `window.document` is assigned to (worryingly, `t` is also used as both `window` and a function). The event listener tries to use `i` as *both*, by checking its `hidden` property, but also *calling* it as a function; but it’s *not* a function.

This script block appears after some ad-related markup, so I assume, this is another ad-related script.

Comment: This is probably due to an upgrade of UglifyJS from v2 to v3. I've been able to reproduce this, working on a fix now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok this was a fun one.

### TL;DR

Our minifier was broken. [It was weak and foolish, so I destroyed it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0lns.png).

Ok, no not really. But we *did* have some legacy minification code that wasn't working quite right and created a naming collision.

### TS;WM (too short; want more)

Essentially what was happening is that we (the Ad Server team) were running [our loader script](https://clc.stackoverflow.com/loader.js) (which is what's embedded on Stack Overflow) through uglify-js during the build process. This removes things like `console.log` statements, strips comments, and all that other standard minify stuff. Including (and this is the important bit) [name mangling](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/mangle).

However, that particular piece of code also was getting run through a server-side minification process (via [AjaxMin](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/)) which had an unfortunate bug: while renaming variables, it apparently doesn't check for collisions with existing function names that already look minified.

In this case, the `load()` function was renamed to `i()` via uglify-js, and *then* AjaxMin renamed *another* variable to `i`, and voila: name collision.

Super edge case, I know. The fix was basically to restructure how we serve this bit of code, and it no longer uses AjaxMin.

Anywho, thanks for the tip, this went under our radar for a while (about 9 days), but it should be fixed now!